# Python type annotations: return type of inherited method

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, type-hinting, mypy

I have created a custom dictionary-like class to simplify merging evaluation metrics across a large dataset. This class implements an `__add__` method to sum up various metrics.

Here is a simplified version of the code I'm working on:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar, Dict


T = TypeVar('T', int, float)


class AddableDict(Dict[str, T]):
    def __add__(self, other: AddableDict[T]) -> AddableDict[T]:
        if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            raise ValueError()
        new_dict = self.__class__()
        all_keys = set(list(self.keys()) + list(other.keys()))
        for key in all_keys:
            new_dict[key] = self.get(key, 0) + other.get(key, 0)
        return new_dict


# AddableIntDict = AddableDict[int]
# this would work just fine, however I need to add a few additional methods


class AddableIntDict(AddableDict[int]):
    def some_int_specific_method(self) -> None:
        pass


def main() -> None:
    x = AddableIntDict()
    y = AddableIntDict()
    x['a'] = 1
    y['a'] = 3

    x += y  # breaks mypy
```

The final line of the program breaks mypy (0.782) with the following error:

`error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "AddableDict[int]", variable has type "AddableIntDict")`

This error makes sense to me.

The code works fine when I define `AddableIntDict` as a type alias of `AddableDict[int]`, as noted in my comment, however because I needed to add additional methods depending on the type of the dictionary's values, as indicated by `some_int_specific_method`, I can't simply use a type alias.

Could anyone point me in the right direction for how to annotate the parent classes's `__add__` method so that it will return the type of the calling class?

(I'm using Python 3.8.3)

Comment: As an aside, `all_keys = set(list(self.keys()) + list(other.keys()))` can just be `all_keys = self.keys() | other.keys()` since the dict keys-view object implement set-like operations already

Comment: Also, as another aside, it looks like this is just re-inventing `collections.Counter`

Comment: Thanks for the `|` tip @juanpa.arrivillaga. I'm familiar with `Counter`s. The class I'm implementing introduces more complicated logic, although it probably could be rewritten to use `Counter`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can refer to "the type of `self`" by using a type variable. This resolves to the appropriate type of either the base class or subclass on which the method is invoked:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Dict


T = TypeVar('T', int, float)
AD = TypeVar('AD', bound='AddableDict')


class AddableDict(Dict[str, T]):
    def __add__(self: AD, other: AD) -> AD: ...


class AddableIntDict(AddableDict[int]):
    def some_int_specific_method(self) -> None: ...

x = AddableIntDict(a=1)
y = AddableIntDict(a=3)
x += y  # works for mypy and others
```

Comment: Note: mypy errors that `AddableDict` is "missing type parameters for generic type" with the `--strict` flag. However it seems you can safely ignore these errors.